# In Hibernate 5 JPA: I need to add an annotated class at runtime, but only for a particular PU

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate3, hibernate-5.x

I have a project which I'm migrating to Hibernate 5 from 3.6, and I want to dynamically add a number of annotated entity classes at runtime. I found about the MetadataSourcesContributor which does allow classes to be added - but I can't find a way to determine which persistence unit is currently being processed. The project has two separate PU's and the new classes need to be added to the second one only.